# Android Multiple Screen Navigation

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 3 activities to navigate. like Activity A, B, C.

From A to B i called startActivityForResult() method and overwrite onActivityResult() method. In B activity onBackPressed() i set the setResult() method and it is working fine.Now from B to C activity I again called startActivityForResult() and overwrite onActivityResult() in B and in C when back pressed I set setResult() and then call finish().

Now the issue is when I back pressed from C it will directly going to the A. I want the back navigation from C-->B--->A

Kindly help me to achieve this.

Comment: Please provide some code of where you start the activities.

Answer (score 0):

Dont call finish() in Activity C. 
onBackPressed() finishes your activity. Beacuse of finish() you are going back one more step.

Remove call to finish() and everything should work as you expect.